# C socket programming: Set ip header's id to 0?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, raw-sockets

I want to send raw IP packets, which works perfectly fine, except for one field in the IP header.

I need to set the IP id to 0. I tried it the following way:

```
    struct iphdr ip;

ip.version = 4;                               // Ipv4
ip.frag_off = 0;                              // IP Fragmentation
ip.tos     = 0;                               // Type of Service - We don't need this
ip.ttl = 64;                                  // Maxmimum value
ip.protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;                    // DHCP uses UDP
ip.check = 0;                                 // The checksum needs to be 0 before being calculated

// We don't yet have an IP Address
if((ip.saddr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0")) == -1) {
    perror("Failed to convert IP address");
    exit(1);
}

ip.daddr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255");      // we have to do a broadcast
ip.id = 0;                                    //  
ip.ihl = 5;                                   // Header length - 5 means no additional options are being sent in the IP header
ip.tot_len = sizeof(struct packet);           // The total length of the Packet
```

I then create a RAW_SOCKET with the IP_HDRINCL option set:

```
      if ((sockd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
      perror("Failed to create socket");
      exit(1);
  }
int hdrincl = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &hdrincl, sizeof(hdrincl)) == -1) {
    perror("Failed to set IP_HDRINCL");
    exit(1);
}
```

I then create a buffer, containing my IP header, UDP header and the payload and send it out.

However, the network stack keeps changing my id in the IP header.  I need to include the IP header, but I also need to disable fragmentation and / or set the IP id to 0. How do I achieve this?

EDIT: I am on Linux

Comment: You are on linux or windows? If you are on windows, sockets aren't the way to do that; try libpcap instead.

Comment: If you check the man page `man 7 raw` you'll see that when `id` is `0` it will be automatically filled in, so that explains why you can't use id 0, however I don't have a solution to actually use id 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux, you can use `AF_PACKET` with `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets instead of `AF_INET` with `SOCK_RAW` and fill an `sockaddr_ll`.

Something like that:

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP))
```

However, to make you program work with Windows too, you should use [libpcap](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut8.html).

Keep in mind that you should resolve the destination's physical address by yourself (On linux, you can try using the `rtnetlink` interface for that).

See more on `packet(7)` and `rtnetlink(7)`. If your project is Open Source, you can use [my old project](https://gitlab.com/ProtocolLearn/ProtocolLearn/tree/master) that doing some of these things (for more information, contact me).